# ¿Por qué en este switch no se cumple ninguno de los case sino que salta directo al default?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, switch

Por qué al realizar las comparaciones el switch se salta todos los casos y va directo al último y solo muestra "Por favor indique un número válido". No entiendo que es lo que estoy haciendo de manera incorrecta...

```
let hora = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una hora en formato militar"));


switch(hora) {
  case (hora > 7 && hora < 11):
    alert("Es de mañana")
    break;

  case (hora > 12 && hora < 19):
    alert("Es de tarde")
    break;

  case ((hora > 20 && hora < 24) || (hora > 0 && hora < 6)):
    alert("Es de noche")
    break;

  default:
    alert("Por favor indique un número válido")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya tienes una respuesta funcional, sin embargo es conveniente explicar el comportamiento de `switch` que, lo único que hace es comparar si la expresión proporcionada como parámetro coincide con una (o más) de las expresiones de cada `case`.

Cuando tienes:

```
let hora = 7;  
switch (hora) {
    case (hora > 0 && hora < 10):
        console.log('Entre cero y diez');
        break;
}
```

La hora está entre el rango seleccionado, pero no entra al `case` *"adecuado"*, porque esto no funciona igual que los `if`. Internamente, el *switch* va a comparar si `hora == (hora > 0 && hora < 10)`, pero, el resultado de esta comparación sería `7 == true` que, por supuesto, el resultado es falso.

Lo que se puede hacer es proporcionar `true` como parámetro y entonces se realizarán comparaciones booleanas:

```js
let hora = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una hora en formato militar"));

switch(true) {
  case (hora >= 7 && hora <= 11):
    alert("Es de mañana");
    break;

  case (hora >= 12 && hora <= 19):
    alert("Es de tarde");
    break;

  case ((hora >= 20 && hora <= 24) || (hora >= 0 && hora <= 6)):
    alert("Es de noche");
    break;

  default:
    alert("Por favor indique un número válido");
}
```

Comment: Entiendo tu respuesta @Triby pero el problema en este código que me envías colocando true como parámetro en el switch es que solo acepta números de un digito y cuando comienzas a colocarle de 10 en adelante salta de inmediato al default

Comment: @OtroMasComoTu, solo había que corregir las comparaciones para considerar todas las posiblidades, por ejemplo `(hora > 7 && hora < 11)` excluye tanto a 7 como a 11.

Comment: Muy buen uso del swtich.

Answer (score 3):

Estas usando mal esta estructura. La sentencia **switch** toma una expresión o variable y en cada **case** la compara con el valor indicado por case,  no evalúa lo que pongas en case como un if.
Para lo que quieres hacer es más adecuado usar varios if anidados.

```
let hora = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una hora en formato militar"));

  if (hora > 7 && hora < 11){
    alert("Es de mañana");
    }
  else{
       if(hora >= 12 && hora <= 19){
          alert("Es de tarde")
          }
       else{
         if((hora >= 20 && hora <= 24) || (hora >= 0 && hora <= 6)){
            alert("Es de noche")
           }
       else{
          alert("Por favor indique un número válido")
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ten en cuenta que en los cases le están pasando valores booleanos, y la variable hora es un int, no un booleano.
Por ejemplo,

```
hora > 7 && hora < 11
```

es verdadero o falso.

En cambio,

```
let hora = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una hora en formato militar"));
```

Podrías hacer:

```
case 7:
case 8:
....
alert("lo que corresponda").
```

Un saludo

Es un entero.

POdrías hacer