# Condicional switch en javascript con múltiples argumentos

Tags: javascript

Tengo este ejercicio que es para comparar los 3 números, lo estoy haciendo con `switch`. Cuando ejecuto el código me sale

> 'los numeros 1, 2 y 3 son iguales'.

¿Será que no estoy poniendo bien la sintaxis del `switch`?

```
var n1=1
var n2=2
var n3=3

function comparacionDeTresNumeros(n1, n2, n3){
    switch (n1,n2,n3) {
        case n1 > n2 && n1 >n3:
            console.log(`el numero mayor es ${n1}`)
            break;
        case n2 > n3 && n2 > n1:
            console.log(`el numero mayor es ${n2}`)
            break;
        case n3 > n1 && n3 >n2:
            console.log(`el numero mayor es ${n3}`)
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`los numeros ${n1}, ${n2} y ${n3} son iguales `)

    }
}
comparacionDeTresNumeros(n1,n2,n3)
```

Comment: Creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/481957/54039) te puede aclarar cómo funciona la estructura `switch`, no puedes usarlo como si se tratara de condicionales `if`.

Comment: mil gracias @Triby me ayudo mucho!

Answer (score 3):

Switch no es apropiado para ese tipo de operaciones, mira aca te dejo un ejemplo compacto, espero te sirva.

Tambien lo modes modificar muy simplemente para que reciba un array y compruebe lo mismo pero de N numeros.

```js
const mayorDeTres = (n1,n2,n3) =>{
  let max = Math.max(n1,n2,n3)
  return max == (n1+n2+n3)/3 ? 
      "Los numeros son iguales"
      :
      "El mayor numero es "+ max
}

console.log(mayorDeTres(2,1,3))
console.log(mayorDeTres(1,2,3))
console.log(mayorDeTres(1,1,1))
console.log(mayorDeTres(100,15,50))
```

Aca esta para N cantidad de numeros

```js
const mayorDeMasDeTres = (numeros) => {
    let max = Math.max.apply(null, numeros)
    let iguales = max == numeros.reduce((a,b) => a+b,0)/numeros.length

    return iguales ? 
      "Los numeros son iguales"
      :
      "El mayor numero es "+ max
}

console.log(mayorDeMasDeTres([1,2,3,3,4,6,10]))
console.log(mayorDeMasDeTres([1,1,1,1,1,1,1]))
console.log(mayorDeMasDeTres([100,15,50,10]))
```

Aca tenes otra forma, usando solo comparacion

```js
const mayorDeTres = (n1,n2,n3) =>
  (n1 == n2 == n3) ? "Los numeros son iguales"
  :
  "El mayor es: "+ ((n1>n2 ? n1:n2) > n3 ? (n1>n2?n1:n2) :n3)



console.log(mayorDeTres(10,2,3))

console.log(mayorDeTres(1,20,3))

console.log(mayorDeTres(1,2,30))

console.log(mayorDeTres(1,1,1))
```

Comment: Tu primer código tiene un bug muy obvio. Sumas los 3 y divides entre 3... si el resultado es el número es que son iguales. Pero las matemáticas no funcionan así, porque si sumo 1 al primer número y resto 1 al último, el resultado de la división es exactamente el mismo pero los números ya no son iguales -> `console.log(mayorDeTres(2,1,3))` Esto imprime "los numeros son iguales" cuando obviamente no lo son :)

Comment: si es verdad, es vestigio de cuando comparaba con Math.max, y no con el n1, no deberia haber tratado de simplificarlo mas.

Answer (score 0):

> Tu error es que switch(exprecion) debe dar un valor valor booleano.Hay
> muchas formas de resolver tu ejercicio en forma mas clara y con menos
> codigo algunas ya te las respondieron en lugar de usar  un switch
> para mostrar tu error te dejo el codigo que si se ejecuta
> Si queres ejecutar acciones diferentes en función de condiciones
> complejas que devuelvan un booleano usa switch(true) tener
> en cuenta que las condiciones deben de ser mutuamente excluyentes
> siempre con un break al final de cada caso
>
> uso de switch(true) Pattern in JavaScript

[switch(true)](https://seanbarry.dev/posts/switch-true-pattern)
Par un codigo mas limpio y claro podes ver que muchas veces el usar switch no es adecuado y puede causar memory leaks mutacion de objetos y demas problemas [switch problemas que puede causar](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-switch-statement-bad-programming-practice-in-Java)

```js
var n1=0
var n2=2
var n3=6

function comparacionDeTresNumeros(n1, n2, n3){
    switch (true) {
        case (n1 > n2) && (n1 >n3):
          console.log(`el numero mayor es ${n1}`)
           break;
        case n2 > n3 && n2 > n1:
            console.log(`el numero mayor es ${n2}`)
          break;
        case n3 > n1 && n3 >n2:
            console.log(`el numero mayor es ${n3}`)
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`los numeros ${n1}, ${n2} y ${n3} son iguales `)

    }
}
comparacionDeTresNumeros(n1,n2,n3)
/*
node /tmp/clk2BXIkyH.js
el numero mayor es 6
*/
```

Comment: Ya no me gusta utilizar `switch`, pero lo de `switch(true)` es como matar mosquitos con un bombardero del ejército. Seguro que funciona, pero el destrozo que vas a causar en el proyecto no vale la pena. Eso acaba creciendo hasta convertirse en un monstruo donde las cláusulas del switch pueden tener 4 renglones de condicionales.... y seguir siendo válidos. Muy, muy mala práctica

Comment: Son patrones para que estén disponibles para ser utilizados cuando sea apropiado. En el ejercicio le piden usar ..En @ngrx/store se uso dentro de los reducers hasta no hace muchos .Todo depende del uso que le des o de lo que te pidan hacer para practicar .En el caso de el el error era enviar tres parámetros que no retornaban un booleano en switch(exprecion)..https://kyleshevlin.com/pattern-matching

Comment: Me quedo especialmente con lo de *cuando sea apropiado*. No digo que no sea un patrón útil y que bien usado sea *"cosa fina"*. Pero enseñárselo a alguien que está aprendiendo sin explicarle lo difícil e inmantenible que puede llegar a ser eso mal usado es peligroso

Comment: La pregunta de el fue estoy usando bien la sintaxis del switch?luego vi varias respuestas y comentarios ninguna denoto el error de no estar utilizando adecuadamente a switch(exprecion) y ejemplificar a el que debe evaluar el switch(exprecion)

Comment: nestdan, me parece super valido, yo no conocia esa forma de usar el switch y ahora que la se, no la voy a usar nunca, pero es bueno saber que existe, tu respuesta agrega mucho valor a la pregunta., y Benito, se ve realmente que sabes pero el espiritu de tus comentarios no es para nada agradable de leer. Hay muchas formas de decir lo mismo, muchas construyen otras destruyen.

Comment: Facundo coincido con vos pero puede ocurrir que se de utilidad switch(true) en casos muy particulares como detalla un link que deje .En cuanto a la pregunta de anonymuus_gp el único sentido era mostrarle a el  de que  switch(n1,n2,n3) no retornaba un valor booleano y ahí estaba el error saludos