# JS - Switch/Case con Regex o OR

Tags: javascript, regex

Es posible hacer en un SWITC/CASE en JS con OR o con regex?

En el código de abajo, sirve cuando comienza con: (a) y (c), pero cuando uso regex (b) o OR (d), dice "undefined".

```js
function getLetter(s) {
    let letter;
    switch(s[0]){
      case 'a' :
        letter = "A"
        break;
      case (/[^b]/).test(s[0]):
        console.log("aloo")
        letter = "A"
        break
      case 'c':
        letter = "A"
        break
      case 'd' || 'e':
      letter = "A"
     }
   console.log(letter) 
}

getLetter("alo")
getLetter("buroo")
getLetter("clon")
getLetter("Don")
```

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/481957/54039) se explica cómo funciona realmente la estructura `switch` y porqué no _"evalúa correctamente"_ las expresiones que estás usando.

Comment: Respondida la parte de OR.

Muchas gracias.

Faltaría la parte de Regex.

Comment: Es lo mismo, `switch(true)` y crea una condición válida en cada case: `case (s[0] == 'd' || s[0] == 'e'):` para el OR y `case (/[^b]/).test(s[0]):` para la expresión regular. El resto también requiere condiciones completas, por ejemplo: `case (s[0] == 'a'):`

Answer (score 1):

Estás formulando mal la expresión regular, en este caso, has puesto

```regex
/[^b]/
```

Lo que estás haciendo es **negar** la *b*, por lo que la expresión no hará match a palabras que contengan la b (efecto contraproducente a la intención principal), por otro lado, puedes hacerlo todo en una expresión regular. La parte de *OR*, se consigue con el operador `|`, que sirve para indicar que se va a formular otra expresión aparte, en la misma expresión principal.

Y por último, no necesitas `switch`, basta con un `if`

```js
function getLetter(s) {
   let letter = (s.match(/^[a-e]/i) || [])[0];
   console.log(letter);
   return letter;
}

getLetter("alo")
getLetter("buroo")
getLetter("clon")
getLetter("Don")
```

Tu expresión te estaba devolviendo `undefined` debido a que la palabra *Don* empieza con D **mayúscula**, en este caso, debes de ponerle la flag `i` (ignore case) para que haga match a la letra sea minúscula o mayúscula

En esta línea

```js
(s.match(/^[a-e]/i) || [])[0];
```

Lo que hacemos básicamente es hacer match a palabras que empiecen con a, b, c, d o e. Creando un rango con la expresión regular. Ej: `[a-z]` creará un rango de la "a" a la "z", mientras que `[a-zA-Z]` creará un rango de la "a" a la "z" también pero usando las letras minúsculas y mayúsculas, en este caso no necesitarías la flag *ignore case*

Cuando no se obtiene ningun match con la expresión, el método devuelve `null`, y para poder indexarlo, dará un error porque `null` no es iterable, para evitar esto, ponemos `|| []`, lo que quiere decir que si el valor primero es `null`, que ponga un array vacío en su lugar, y de todas maneras será indexable